# Using mouse inside class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, mouse, flash-cs4

I make a simple class which is not extended from any other flash classes. The problem is, using mouse coordination inside this simple class. This is my code for the class.

```
package src { 

      public dynamic class guider{
      public function move01(xxx:int, yyy:int , speed:int) {
            trace (mouseX);
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```

After compile it gives the error: “**1120: Access of undefined property mouseX** “ which is obvious. I try to figure it out with importing some classes related to mouse. So I rewrite my code like this:

```
package src {
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;     
    public dynamic class guider{
        public function move01(xxx:int, yyy:int , speed:int) {
            trace (getDefinitionByName("flash.ui.Mouse").mouseX);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now there is **not** any error on compile but when I use it, it trace out “**undefined**”! What is my problem here?

Note: This class is used for real time interaction with mouse and I prefer to make it simple to get a higher performance. The return value of this function will be a number based on mouse x coordination and other inputs. Here I use “**return true;”** just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

in the constructor of the class you should pass the stage (of type Stage) then say:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);

private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        trace(event.stageX + " " + event.stageY);
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

You cant use Object (extend none) as your baseclass if you want to know where the mouse is relative to that object. To find the mouse you need to show that object on the stage to find the position the mouse is in. Therefor you can use the [MouseX](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mouseX) function of the DisplayObject. So extend that one instead of MovieClip. Or you can find the mouse again by using the stage. Again pass the stage to the class in the constructor and save it in a private or protected var.

```
public function move01(xxx:int, yyy:int , speed:int):void {
        trace (stage.mouseX);
}
```